# Rebase template function in bottle python doesn't render the template as it should

Tags: python, template-engine, bottle

I'm trying to reproduce the basic example of the rebase function from the bottle documentation, but when my template is rendered the html code is encoded and my tags are replaced by their corresponding html code.

My template:

```
% rebase('base.tpl', title='Page Title')
<p>Page Content ...</p>
```

My base template:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>{{title or 'No title'}}</title>
</head>
<body>
  {{base}}
</body>
</html>
```

The final html rendered:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
      &lt;p&gt;Page Content ...&lt;/p&gt;

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, my template is included at the right place, but it's like if the template engine had escaped it for security reasons and I don't know whys.

I'm surprised being the only one having this issue.

I'm using bottle v0.12.5 and reproduced the issue on different environnements (MacOSX & Ubuntu)

Any thoughts or ideas? Thanks

Comment: I just have found my answer in an other question i didn't found before.
I have to tell Bottle this code is safe adding an exclamation mark before the variable base in my base template:

    {{!base}}

And it works.

Thanks stackoverflow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTML special characters are automatically escaped. You can unescape them by adding a `!` at the beginning of your expression:

```
<body>
  {{!base}}
</body>
```

[You can see the documentation about this here.](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/stpl.html#inline-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

I think;

The document of Bottle v0.12(stable) is not correct. Because it said {{ base }}.
Bottle dev (development) is correct. Thus, {{ ! base }}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).